# Que código javascript posso utilizar para substituir todas as imagens do html com extensão webp para png quando o navegador for o Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, webp

Converti todas as imagens do site para o formato **.webp**. Porém, o navegador Safari (Apple) ainda não o reconhece.

Portanto, mantive no servidor todas as imagens também em **.png**. Eu gostaria de inserir um código javascript que desse um `.replace()` em todas as imagens do documento `HTML` quando o navegador for o Safari, substituindo **.webp** por **.png**.

Abaixo um exemplo:

```
<!-- Link para os navegadores Chrome, Edge e Firefox: -->
<img class="imagemsafari" src="images/marcas/Ecommerce-life-detox.webp" alt="Life Detox">

<!-- Link par ao navegador Safari: -->
<img class="imagemsafari" src="images/marcas/Ecommerce-life-detox.png" alt="Life Detox">
```

Até o momento a única opção que encontrei é utilizando o código abaixo. Que infelizmente só muda um **id**.
Segue abaixo:

```
<script>
    if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1 ) {
        var str = document.getElementById("imagemsafari").src; 
        var res = str.replace(/webp/g, "png");
        document.getElementById("imagemsafari").src = res;
    }
</script>
```

Consegui explicar?

Comment: Não é somente Safari que não suporta **.webp** ... você deveria verificar o suporte ao formato em vez do navegador

Answer (score 1):

#### Você não precisa de javascript para isso!

Você pode utilizar a tag [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) e colocar as duas imagens (webp e png), sendo assim, caso a primeira imagem dê erro ao ser carregada, o próprio navegador entende que deve procurar pela segunda e assim sucessivamente.

#### Utilizando o elemento picture

Segue um [exemplo](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/) da utilização do elemento picture:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

Observe que foi necessário passar 2 elementos `source` e um elemento `img` neste exemplo. Neste caso, como são duas uri e tipos de imagem diferentes, definimos isso com os 2 primeiros source, na ordem em que queremos que seja carregado e deixamos uma tag `img` que o browser vai "injetar" o primeiro source que der certo.

Comment: Navegadores antigos, todos os IE's e vários mobiles não suportam `<picture>`

Comment: É que na pergunta fala sobre o Safari... Não li nada sobre essa restrição de navegador antigo e não sei adivinhar ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar tag picture:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="path/imagem.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="path/imagem.png">
</picture>
```

Ou

Você pode colocar um atributo nas suas imagens assim: `<img data-img ... />` e fazer algo como isso:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) { 
        var sources = document.querySelectorAll("[data-img]"); 
        for (var i in sources) {
            var url = sources[i];
            if (url.src.indexOf('.webp') !== -1) {
                url.src = url.src.replace(/\.webp/gim, ".png");  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ou pode colocar uma regra caso ocorra erro de interpretação na imagem assim:

```
<img onerror="this.src='path/arquivo-alternativo.png'" src="path/arquivo-alternativo.webp">
```

Ou pode criar uma pasta para o safari e apontar o path das suas imagens:

```
 var dir = '/images/'
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) { 
     dir = '/safari-images/';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza utilizar os elementos `<picture>` e `<source>` é o método mais canônico visto que os navegadores modernos já o suportam e decidem adequadamente qual formato usar.

Contudo utilizar `JavaScript` é uma boa opção caso queira evitar ter de modificar manualmente todas as entradas em todos os documentos de seu site.

Uma vez que você já tem uma duplicata dos formatos você deve:

- 1: verificar o suporte ao formato (caso não suporte)
- 2: buscar todas as referencias de elementos `<img>`
- 3: iterar sobre esta lista e verificar se  o **src** contém ".webp"
- 4: modificar todos os atributos **.src** encontrados

Algo como isto:

```js
// no topo do seu script checar se o navegador supoorta o formato
var BrowserSupportWebpCheck = document.createElement('canvas').toDataURL('image/webp').indexOf('data:image/webp') === 0

// se o navegador não suportar o formato ".webp"
if ( !BrowserSupportWebpCheck ) {
    // buscar todos os elementos "<img>"
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    // ES5 usa "forEach" ... suporta IE 9 em diante
    images.forEach((item, index, array) => {
        if ( item.src.indexOf('.webp') !== -1 ) {
            // substituir o "src" do elemento
            item.src = item.src.replace('.webp', '.png')
            // apenas para este exemplo, mostrar
            console.log(item.src)
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
<img src="path/to/image.webp">
```

A trecho de código acima vai "printar" no console todos os atributos **src** encontrados e modificados para **.png** ... claro, só irá faze-lo de fato se o navegar não suportar o formato **.webp**

Deve-se observar também que não é somente o Safari que não suporta o formato **.webp** e o elemento `<picture>`, navegadores antigos e alguns "mobile" também não suportam.

---

**Referencias de suporte:**

- [suporte ao formato **.webp**](https://caniuse.com/#search=webp)
- [suporte ao elemento `<picture>`](https://caniuse.com/#search=picture)
- [suporte ao método `Array.forEach()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach)
- [suporte basico ao `Canvas.toDataURL()`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas)